# jQuery using target on mouseover on appended elements does not work

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the class name of an element that I append to the document using `.target`, but it returns undefined.

I append an element with the class name `.marker` to a larger element called `#world`.

```
var marker = $('<div class="marker hide new"></div>');
$('#world').append(marker);
```

Then on `mousemove` I want to do something when my mouse is over the new `.marker`.  But, when the element is appended, It returns `undefined` when I'm over it.

```
$(document).on('mousemove', '#world', function(e){
    console.log($(e.target));
});
```

This returns `undefined` when I'm over the new, appended `.marker`.  Any way to show the actual element?

Comment: Your code seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/zvLg6815/1/  Could you create a fiddle where the problem is reproduced?

Comment: I will try to make a fiddle with my stuff in there.  Thank you for doing that for me.  I'll look into this.

Comment: The code seems to work. What were you planning to do on scrolling over $('#world').